# Make a list of all pages of a site in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to list all pages of a site in Python for scraping with BeautifulSoup. What I currently have is this:

```
team_urls = ['http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/thinking+out+loud_21083784.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/photograph_21058341.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/a+team_20983411.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/i+see+fire_21071421.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/perfect_21113253.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/castle+on+the+hill_21112527.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/supermarket+flowers_21113249.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/lego+house_20983415.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/even+my+dad+does+sometimes_21085123.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/kiss+me_20983414.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/shape+of+you_21113143.html',
            'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/i+see+fire_21071421.html'
]
```

I would like to call a function to pull all sites starting with `http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/`, as I know the current list is sloppy and there are approximately 30 more available that I'd rather not just add manually.

Comment: This question is very unspecific and no code has been provided. By unspecific I mean it doesn't make sense, please try to be more meticulous with your quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.x, you could create your list of subdomains as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import urllib2 

base_url = 'http://www.lyricsfreak.com' 
request = urllib2.Request(base_url + '/e/ed+sheeran/', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')

urls = []

for tr in soup.select('tbody tr'):
    urls.append(base_url + tr.td.a['href'])

print urls
```

This would create a `urls` list starting:

```
['http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/a+team_20983411.html', 'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/afire+love_21084845.html', ...
```

---

In Python 3.x, this can be modified as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import urllib    

base_url = 'http://www.lyricsfreak.com' 
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url + '/e/ed+sheeran/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')

urls = []

for tr in soup.select('tbody tr'):
    urls.append(base_url + tr.td.a['href'])

print(urls)
```

---

Or use the `requests` library as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import requests

base_url = 'http://www.lyricsfreak.com' 
response = requests.get(base_url + '/e/ed+sheeran/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

urls = []

for tr in soup.select('tbody tr'):
    urls.append(base_url + tr.td.a['href'])
```

Install using:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, so there is an issue with urllib and urllib.reuest.urlopen. I tried exchanging urllib2 and urllib2.urlopen, but it returned urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Is this an issue with the sites I'm trying to access or something in my code (I left everything else you suggested the same)?

Comment: The library in 2.x is a bit different, I have updated it accordingly. I normally use the `requests` library to do these kinds of requests.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. As far as the difference between urllib2 and requests you mentioned, would you mind explaining how they differ here? I'm just starting out and am not married to either method, but would like to understand the relative merits of each better.

Comment: They changed the way it works between versions a bit. But also when I used the a similar method in Python 2.x, the website refused the connection (as it didn't like the Python user agent string) so I needed to change the way it worked to add a user agent. I would recommend you itake a look at the [request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. This is easier to use.